# Hide DIVs but show sub-class in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide call DIVs with the class 'row' but display a table that has the class 'print'. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="print">
        <tr><td>Monday</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS I'm trying:

```
.row { display: none; }
.row .print {
    display: block !important;
}
```

I've tried a few options but can't get the table to display.

Thanks

Comment: When an element is hidden, it's hidden with all its children.

Answer (score 3):

You can use simple jquery for this

```
$('.print').parent().show();
```

Css

```
.row { display: none; }
```

Here is <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7rC8P/2/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Give the the row you want to display an ID like this:

```
<div class="row" id="row-displayed">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="print">
    <tr><td>Monday</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

With the CSS:

```
.row { display: none; }
#row-displayed { display: block }
```

Or you could also give that row another class (such as row-displayed) with the same CSS, just targeting `.row-displayed` and making sure that the CSS for that is below the .row CSS. That would work because of the cascading nature of CSS.

Comment: I'm trying to CSS to print a page created in WordPress and OptimizePress. It has DIVs all with the class 'row' but I want to show the row with the table. There is no way to add a class or ID to a row in OptimizePress.

Comment: Then you should take a look at Manwal's solution. It will require javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in CSS you can use JQuery for you to achieve what you want.

But if you want to use JQuery try this one :

```
$(document).ready(function () {            
        $(".print").closest('.row').show();
    });
```

Comment: And what? This is too brief to be an helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {            
            $(".print").closest('.row').show();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you try this:

```
.row * {
    display: none;
}
.row .print {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Since a hidden element always hides its children, what you want to do is hiding the unwanted children, not the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really the case that the elements with the class `.row` have to be invisible while printing and only the children with the `.print` have to be visible?

Another way of solving would be to make all children of `.row` invisible expect if they have the class `.print`:

```
.row > *  {
    display: none;
}

.row > .print {
    display: block;
}
```

This would only work if there is no *TextNode*  as direct child of `.row` that has to be invisible.